# How to move a unique_ptr without custom deleter to another unique_ptr with custom deleter?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, move-semantics

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct TestStruct {
    int a = 100;
};

struct StructDeleter {
    void operator()(TestStruct *ptr) const {
        delete ptr;
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<TestStruct, StructDeleter> MakeNewStruct() {
    std::unique_ptr<TestStruct> st(new TestStruct());

    std::unique_ptr<TestStruct, StructDeleter> customDeleterSt(std::move(st));
    std::cout << customDeleterSt->a << std::endl;
    return customDeleterSt;
}

int main() {
    auto a = MakeNewStruct();
    std::cout << a->a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code can not be compiled, how to move `st` to `customDeleterSt`?
I get a `st` unique_ptr from the `st` creation interface, and I use the custom deleter to hide the implementation of `st` from my users, so how to move a unique_ptr without custom deleter to a unique_tr with custom deleter?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In this specific case, since your `StructDeleter` is functionally equivalent to the default deleter, you can do `std::unique_ptr<TestStruct, StructDeleter> customDeleterSt(st.release());` Note that this trick doesn't work in general.

Comment: Because the deleter type is a template parameter, it is part of the `unique_ptr`'s type. As such, you can move a `unique_ptr` into another type of `unique_ptr` only when the source pointer being moved is implicitly convertible to the target pointer type *AND the source deleter is assignment-compatible with the target deleter*.

Comment: *"I get a `st` unique_ptr from the st creation interface"* -- seems kind of odd to provide a deleter for something you did not allocate. Which could explain why you're running into problems (which I acknowledge is not the question you asked, but could explain a "not useful" downvote).

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply! The interface actually is `tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile` and its return type is `std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel>`, and I need to include the tensorflow header in my .cpp instead of .h, which makes it possible that my users do not need include tensorflow headers to build his library, that's why I use a custom deleter in my implementation, if there is another better way, plz tell me know, thanks!

Comment: @RaymondChen release() works! Actually my StructDeleter is just delete! Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how your custom deleter solves any problems. Either way, clients need to have access to the destructor of `tflite::FlatBufferModel`.

Comment: @RaymondChen clients will pass my library the input data, which whill be passed to the model to inference, and my library will return the result, that's to say, clients do not care any tensorflow things, and my library destruct the model. the declaration of the custom deleter function is in the header, and the delete implementation, which requires the full implementation of FlatBufferModel is in the source, so when clients include my header, they do not need include tensorflow headers :D

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you are doing. You're going to declare `StructDeleter`'s `operator() in your header, but not implement it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the brute-force way is to have the source `.release()` to the constructor of the destination.  However there is a much more elegant solution (imho):

Add an implicit conversion from `std::default_delete<TestStruct>` to `StructDeleter`:

```
struct StructDeleter {
    StructDeleter(std::default_delete<TestStruct>) {}  // Add this

    void operator()(TestStruct *ptr) const {
        delete ptr;
    }
};
```

Now the code works with the existing move construction syntax.

Whether this is done via the converting constructor, or `.release()`, if `StructDeleter` can't (for whatever reasons) properly delete a pointer that `std::default_delete` handles, this will result in undefined behavior.  It is only because `StructDeleter` calls `delete ptr` that either of these techniques works.

[As written, `TestStruct` does not need to be a complete type at the point of `delete`.  However should `TestStruct` acquire a non-trivial destructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#5), you will also need to ensure that for any code that calls `StructDeleter::operator()(TestStruct*)`, that `TestStruct` is a complete type, otherwise you're back into UB territory again.  [This assurance is one of the things that `std::default_delete<TestStruct>` does for you](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.dltr#dflt-3) and that `StructDeleter` (as written) does not.

If it is intended to keep `~TestStruct()` trivial, it would be a good idea to add:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<TestStruct>::value);
```